# Store Highcharts in Javascript Function - How to?

Tags: javascript, function, highcharts

I am trying to store the entire Highcharts/Highstocks script into a function for js to make things a bit more compact and easier to replicate.

```
$(function() {
// Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : [[1,2],[4,5]],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

This is basically whats in the file highchartsfunc.js that I call for the function. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You already have it in a function, just one that executes immediately.  Here it is in a callable form with the data and renderto defined by the caller:

```
function createNewChart(data, render) {
// Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : render
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

then you can call it like this from wherever you like:

```
createNewChart([[1,2],[4,5]], 'container');
```

Comment: Wow thank you. I know it's quite an obvious thing once I look at it. I just started learning jscript last night so thank you quite a bit for even just pointing out the obvious!!!

Comment: Are you able to have php in something like this?